# Can you launch electron app from nodejs and have it communicate back and forth?

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to create GUI for terminal app. It'd be nice if I could code it with js/css/html. Electron seems like a good candidate. Is it possible, if yes how, to launch an electron app, have it talk to nodejs process running in background.

At this point I'm exploring different options.

Answer (score 1):

Electron comes with NodeJs support. You don't need to run a background process to do that. But if that is required you can do this via a socket connection (something like websockets). [Here](https://socket.io/) is a good candidate for that.

Comment: so i build two apps one electron and one nodejs, then both open a connection to a third app which is socket server. correct?

Comment: Umm, yeah that is possible or you implement a socket server in nodejs app without creating a whole new app

Answer (score 0):

Why you are creating NodeJS process separately. see when you launch an **Electron** application you will have two process i.e. **main Process and render process**. if you want you can create more then 1 renderer process.

in each process i.e. whether it is renderer or main process all NodeJS api is working .

and you can communicate with other process using **ipc Communication**.

Hope it will work